# How to upload, display and erase images using node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express, server, image-uploading

I need to upload an image to the server (built in nodejs) and display it for everyone in the html site. When someone does the same thing the last image can go away I don't need to store it.
Anyone can help me with this?
Best

Comment: you can use this https://github.com/sthnaqvi/file-upload-nodejs for image upload but you should create a route for image rendering that code is only for data upload

Answer (score 3):

There are many tutorials and npm packages are available for upload file using nodejs

[Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

[Express Fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload)

[Fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fileupload)

[Ng2 File Upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-file-upload)

[Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/express-file-uploads-with-multer) you can find a tutorial

Answer (score 2):

hope this helps

in this example if you pass id and folder same the file gets replaced, change as per your requirements

I have used [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

```
const router = express.Router();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs');
var multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

router.get('/:folder/:id', async (req, res) => {
    let filepath = path.join(__dirname + `/../images/${req.params.folder}/${req.params.id}.png`);
    res.sendFile(filepath);
});

const upload = async (image, folder, id) => {

    let dir = `images`;

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }

    dir = `images/${folder}`;

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }

    await image.mv(`images/${folder}/${id}.png`);

    return `${config.DOMAIN}/images/${folder}/${id}`;
}

router.post('/:folder/:id', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    try {

        let image = req.files.image;

        if (!image)
            return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Image not provided!' });

        const imageUrl = await upload(image, req.params.folder, req.params.id);

        if (imageUrl)
            res.status(201).send({ message: "Image uploaded", url: imageUrl });

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Error uploading image!", error: e.toString(), req: req.body });
    }
});

router.delete('/:folder/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        fs.unlinkSync(`images/${req.params.folder}/${req.params.id}.png`);

        res.status(201).send({ message: "Image deleted" });

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send({ message: "Error deleting image!", error: e.toString(), req: req.body });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you show me an example to call this file from cliente (angular)